# Websphere MQ receive channel start up slow

Tags: ibm-mq

I have QmgrA (WMQ 7.5 Solaris) and QmgrB( Aix, WMQ older than 7.5).

```
QmgrA --sdr channel-> QmgrB 
QmgrA <--recv channel-- QmgrB
```

Sender channel from QmgrA to QmgrB starts up in a few seconds after I issue `start chl`. (Substate(MQGET))

However the recv channel starts up like more than 30minutes later (substate(RECEIVE)). Both sdr and recv channels are configured with SSL. I have disabled OCSP on QmgrA. However problem still persist.

Do you have an troubleshooting tips for such situation? Any channel tuning parameters to configure? or Solaris resources to fine tune? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a number of steps in the process of getting a channel to start that can take some time. Often these sorts of delays only exist in one direction, just as your problem shows. OCSP is one of many such possibilities, and you already tried ruling that one out. However, rather than just guessing at what they might be, we should try to discover what it is from looking at the channel status SUBSTATE value. I see that you are already familiar with it. SUBSTATE(RECEIVE) is a good state for a receiver channel to be in. What we want to know is what SUBSTATE do you see at the sender (on QMgr B) and the receiver (on QMgr A) during the 30 minute delay. There is a SUBSTATE for each of the possible delaying issues, so seeing what value is shown will point at what the problem is.

**Related Reading**

1. [Channel states and substates](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q015610_.htm)
2. [Channel Sub Status Blog Post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/mq_channel_sub_status)

Comment: Dorothy mentioned "30minutes later" ?!
Was that a misspelling ?

Comment: @gouda - I have no way of knowing - dorothy never came back with any further information about what SUBSTATE values were seen. Perhaps if you add your comment to the original question, the author will see it and can be prompted to reply.

Comment: Sorry Morag, but Dorothy's last activity was May 1st of 2015 - that's way too long ago.

Comment: Interestingly @gouda, I notice that the comment from you that I replied to 2 days ago was in 2014 as well, so I'm not quite sure why SO notified me of a new comment on here when it was 2014! Perhaps someone commented and deleted it again before I clicked on the notification. Never mind. Cheers!